# How can I disable 'autoscroll from source' in Visual-Studio-Code

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

`Code Version - 1.7.1`

I find this to be one of the most annoying parts of my day.

How can i disable 'autoscroll from source' in  Visual-Studio-Code?

In Android Studio it is possible to enable/disable `Auto Scroll to/from source`. I'm looking for a way to disable this in Visual-Studio-Code.

Thank you

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Open your user settings and set `"explorer.autoReveal": false`. This setting is listed under "File Explorer" on the default settings side.

Comment: I was about to throw the entire damn thing out the window. Turns out it can be a surprisingly good editor with these _features_ turned off.

Comment: thank you! that feature is the most annoying UX I had in VS Code. besides that, it's a pretty good editor

Comment: I changed the right side and the left side autoReveal setting still shows the old setting. Whey make a stupid setting page like this? Edit: After reading more I noticed that the left side is the default settings. This is the dumbest thing i've ever seen. Just have a radio button true or false. Why show the default settings and confuse people?

Comment: also is there a Scroll to source file like thing? think the target icon in Webstorms explorer

Comment: focusNoScroll is the better option I think, it makes it the same way as in JetBrains IDE

Answer (score 2):

May you want to focus to "File Explorer" from "current editing file" you can set `"Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar"` in Short cut setting file. after set `"explorer.autoReveal": false`